# Issue with double-escaped entities in the link

Tags: hugo

I am getting double-escaped entities in the link in a post. For example, a link `What's the difference` becomes `What&amp;rsquo;s the difference`.

The problem is similar to this https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/solved-why-is-page-title-getting-double-escaped-entities/14935 however it didn't help me solve this.

Why is this happening? How do I solve it?

The code for the blog is available here - https://github.com/desecho/blog

Comment: Scrap you need to show your code, context, some reference. Make it so that someone can in fact answer you. If we look at your question to a ne plus ultra: their is no actual question. So, I ASSUME your question is "why is this happening and how do I solve it", the answer is "something is wrong with your code/evironment/parameters or implementation", meaning, we would need to see at least the code, to help you resolve...

Comment: @Rogelio I've added a link to the code on GitHub.

Comment: Awesome Scrap, almost there mate, where/what part of the repo has the code in question?

Comment: It's here - https://github.com/desecho/blog/search?q=What%27s+the+difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your renderhook:
<a href="{{ .Destination | safeURL }}"{{ with .Title}} title="{{ . }}"{{ end }}{{ if strings.HasPrefix .Destination "http" }} target="_blank"{{ end }}>{{ .Text }}

Change it to:

<a href="{{ .Destination | safeURL }}"{{ with .Title}} title="{{ . }}"{{ end }}{{ if strings.HasPrefix .Destination "http" }} target="_blank"{{ end }}>{{ .Text | safeHTML }}

That should do the trick.

Now, the reason why is, well Turtles all the way down, but, realize that Hugo is working with a Markdown engine "goldmark" and you have your config set "unsafe=true", but even beyond that you now have HUGO creating/building with your render hook back to markdown. Not clear to me how they all work together, but their is empirically a lot of back and forth...
So... The above should be fine.

Please test and let me know.

(Providing your code was key, and probably a note for your future-self, if the above resolves your problem, of that).

Bien suerte!